# SQL/SAS fuzzy Logic on integer variable

Tags: sql, sas, fuzzy-logic

My goal is to write some SQL code or use the SAS query builder that will perform a fuzzy logic search on an numeric variable.

As an example; the image below has two variables. The first variable is a concatenation of several different variables. Using the first variable as a subset I want to use fuzzy logic to identify the numbers highlighted in variable two. The whole dataset will have millions of rows of data while the number of subsets in variable one will run into the tens of thousands.

I have also considered creating a new variable which includes variable two & one and doing a fuzzy logic search on that new variable. This method might produce unwanted matches though so my preference is the first method.

[Data snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPIHo.jpg)

I literally don't know where to start on this one.  At present all I have managed to do is identify functions that perform fuzzy logic searches on character variables (for example SPEDIS and SOUNDEX) & not on numeric variables.

Does anyone know a function that will perform a fuzzy logic search on an integer variable?  Do you have sample code?

I am new to both SAS/SQL but a quick learner.  :)

Thanks in advance

Paul

(post edited in response to comments below)

Comment: What's an example of your fuzzy logic?

Comment: Reeza, thanks for your question.  Nothing to complicated a list of financial values to two decimal places.  For example:  1001,34 & 2341.78 & 4432.78 & 7896.90 and so on.

Comment: Your question would be clearer if you included some typical expected inputs and outputs and anything you have tried so far to achieve the desired result.

Comment: edited original post in response to comments. Thanks Paul

Comment: Have you tried converting the numeric values to strings and running the fuzzy logic functions on them?

Answer (score 0):

I think Rob has put you on the right track. Convert the numbers to text, then you can use a cartesian join in proc sql with the `COMPGED` or `COMPLEV` functions to compare pairs of values with the same ID and provide a similarity score for each pair. You can then decide what the score cutoff is for something to be considered a match.